# add Global PHP code field to Views on condition

Tags: 7, views

I want to add PHP field to View based on condition that certain logic field in content item is checked. How can I check that it is checked in PHP code?

More concisely: how can I check if some product's field is checked in Views?

The View is just showing list of contents

Comment: The question is very vague. Add some more information - e.g. which version of Drupal are you using, which shopping cart module are you using, what does the view do etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not followed a correct way, these are the steps to create a custom field on the basis of value of an existing text field are :

1. Add a field in any content type on basis of whose value you want to
   display a custom field.
2. Add contents of that content type filling value of newly created
   field say its a checkbox having 0 or 1 as its value.
3. Create a view of that content type.
4. Add fields and a custom field having some value, say ;

   ```
   <?php 
   echo 'Astha Chauhan';
   ?>
   ```

   in output code field.

   1. Then add a filter of type Global:PHP and add a filter code
      accordingly:

      ```
        <?php    
            if ( $row->field_test_field == '2') {
             return $row->php; 
            }
            else { 
             return 'null'; 
            }  
         ?>
      ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a product's field in your view based on whose value you want to add a custom field. Rite ???

- If yes then add a field whose value you want to check in your view.
- Then add a Global PHP field (note that the field whose value you want to check should be arranged prior to Glbal PHP field)
- Add php logic there by using available tokens of previous field.

Comment: Mmm. I want to add custom field if one logic product's field is set to true. But products are displayed not considering this field value. So to say, I just want to add extra block to some products.

Comment: Did you set value for this field in all your products ????

Comment: Yes, its value is set by default to 0, and on some products I set 1 and want to add extra field if it's so